# GIthub revert to singlefile out of multiple files

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Let's say we have an `xyz` folder in Git which contains `f1.txt`, `f2.txt`, `f3.txt` which are commited and pushed to GitHub. If we want only `c.txt` to be reverted back, how would it be possible?

I tried `git revert <commitid> -- c.txt` which shows

```
git revert 2ndline_f2.txt -- f2.txt
fatal: bad revision 'f2.txt'
```

I tried to push the code from Git to GitHub and tried few commands:

```
git clone <repo>
cd XYZ
git checkout -b revert_branch
git revert tagorcommitid  ex : git revert 2ndline_f2.txt -- f2.txt
fatal: bad revision 'f2.txt'
```

Comment: Uh, `git restore`?

Answer (score 1):

[`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) is supposed to revert commits, not files.
Hence, the error message `fatal: bad revision 'f2.txt'`.

[`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) can indeed, as commented, restore a file from a previous revision:

```
git restore -s oldCommit -SW -- f2.txt
```

That would restore and add to the index `f2.txt` from an old commit.

Comment: Since we download the code from from github we see the latest commit id and I dont think you will get the history of that  code , is it really goes to previous commit if we use restore I think restore would work from git perceptive right?

Comment: @Krishna `git restore -s oldCommit` will restore a file from a fixed old commit SHA1 that you will indicate. A `git log` will show you the history of the code.